# matplotlib swap x and y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Hello I have made a plot in matplot lib using pandas however I need to swap my x and y axis.

Here is my plot:

broomstick plot
[image: broomstick plot]

however i need it to look like this:

correct broomstick plot
[image: correct broomstick plot]

I'm using a pandas dataframe to plot the data.

I've looked over some documentation and other posts regarding swapping the x and y axis and haven't found any easy way to do this.
Here some of my python code:

python code
[image: python code]

Any resources or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You need to include your `y_vals` as an additional column. So with this you can just specify your axis here `df.plot(x=, y=)`:

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.cos(x)

df = pd.DataFrame({'y': y, 'x': x})

df.plot(x='x')
plt.show()

df.plot(x='y')
plt.show()
```

Plots:

[image]
[image]