# Matplotlib/Pyplot equivalent of ggplot coord_flip to swap x and y coordinates?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a single NumPy array with ozone values which I want to be plotted with the mixing ratio on the x-axis and the pressure level on the y-axis.

In R and ggplot this can be done by a simple coord_flip(), but I can't find a way to do this simply in pyplot. I tried with the orientation option, and try to set the x value to the array but both don't work.

The example below, where I want the Vertical level to be the y-axis and O3 ppmv as the x-axis.

[image: Graph]

Thanks

Comment: not sure if an equivalent function exists, but this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856591/matplotlib-swap-x-and-y-axis. you can also combine invert_xaxis and invert_yaxis, see stackoverflow.com/questions/2051744/reverse-y-axis-in-pyplot Although I know this is not exactly what you want!

Comment: Just replace `plt.plot(x, y)` with `plt.plot(y, x)`?  The question would be much clearer if you'd add some MVE.

Comment: @JohanC I only have a single dimension array, so there is no x/y value. Just plt.plot(array)

Comment: Well, in that case `plt.plot(array, np.arange(len(array)))` should work.  If you only have one array, matplotlib by default takes the numbers `0,1,2,...` for the x-axis. If you'd added some minimal code things would have been much clearer.