# Vertically draw plot with matplotlib where each row in an array is a line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset, an even numpy array where each row represents a line:

```
matrix = np.random.rand(10,10)
```

Ultimately, I would like a graph like this:

[image]

Which I have made before in R. But I can't get it to work in Python. I'm not too proficient yet with Python, and have to use it this time.

I simply plot with:

```
plt.plot(matrix)
```

Which results in a good starting point:

[image: Image2]

My first step would be to flip the x and y axis, but the plot function requires an x_vals and y_vals, which my array does not have. There are just values. How can I (for starters) swap the x- and y-axis so that each row in the array gets drawn as an individual vertical line as shown in the image above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib/Pyplot equivalent of ggplot coord\_flip to swap x and y coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66278863/matplotlib-pyplot-equivalent-of-ggplot-coord-flip-to-swap-x-and-y-coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide `x` values, `matplotlib` will just use a range.

Try:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matrix = np.random.rand(10,10)
x_vals = np.arange(10)
for y_vals in matrix:
    plt.plot(y_vals, x_vals)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you sure you have `plt.show()` outside the `for` loop? If so, you'll need to make a figure/axis and explicitly plot all the lines on it.